# How to correctly mock i18n for Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mocking, jestjs, i18next

I have a container in react-native that is importing the typical kind of function that we usually store at `utils` directory such as `capitaliseWord()` or whatever.

One of the functions of that `utils` module uses `t`, so we import `i18n` inside that `utils` folder in order to be able to use `t`

We use `languageDetector` inside our `i18n` to detect the user's mobile language. Because `languageDetector` needs `deviceLocale` (e.g UK, US, NL, etc), and Jest runs on a different context, if I try to do test the container, I will get `Cannot read property 'deviceLocale' of undefined`.

So I created a manual `__mocks__` directory (as https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules states) and I created my own `i18n` that just injects the `deviceLocale` string manually, in order to be able to run the tests.

Turns out the test ignores the `__mocks__/i18n` and points directly to the original one... Any ideas of what it could go wrong?

And my jest config inside `package.json`
https://gist.github.com/e00dd4ee41b06265632d3bcfe76e7cb0

original `i18n.js`
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/3c48c6017a82356914f0ad69d7251496

mocked `i18n.js`
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/17e322340581fb948ed7e319ae4a5ac9 (notice the `detect` key inside `languageDetector` has been manually mocked)

Component to be tested
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/20dc0c5b1a6d2ee709b7a71ec7b819c1

utils.js
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/1c5df0f71d50462d75234365ae1e4aaf

Comp.test.js
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/2a84880bee3a99fa51fc3e28cfa8f913

Error:
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/012ee0889ebbe2b93b2108d93543e19c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not in the mock, but the import! Try this time requiring the component in the test, after the mock has been injected:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

jest.mock('../../config/i18n');

describe('<Comp />', () => {
  it('must match the snapshot', () => {
    // Require here instead of importing on top
    const Comp = require("./Comp").default;

    // state and props properly set up
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comp />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I tried this locally and it's working fine: the module gets mocked. I simplified a lot my example so perhaps you run into some new error but technically this should solve your problem.

**EDIT**: pushed my working example to github [here](https://github.com/josemigallas/jest-manual-mock-example) in case it's for any help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Both 1 and 2 are properly set up. I have updated some info in the OP as requested.
Thanks again.

Comment: Taking a second look.. Not that it really matters but are you missing a slash here? https://gist.github.com/pavilion/e00dd4ee41b06265632d3bcfe76e7cb0#file-package-json-L6

Comment: Not really. https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/react-native.html#example-configuration-for-jest

Comment: All right, my bad! I think of 2 solutions: 1 you simply mock your component. You'd test utils functions in a separate test so you can take it for granted when testing the component. Or 2, have you taken a look at modulenamemapper? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 1st one, please? I am not sure how can I implement that. About the 2nd, I added it like this https://gist.github.com/pavilion/4ce709d7e7c84cff3d0e34aa980a86dc
but I am having this error
https://gist.github.com/pavilion/4ee8f5bb6cb304e8b9190f1f8ff98011

Comment: @ismaeloliva I finally found a solution, forget all what I said before!

Comment: I have tried with
`jest.mock("../../config/i18n");`
`import Comp from './Comp'` but that doesnt work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186853/discussion-between-josemigallas-and-ismael-oliva).